# Jquery working local but not on published site

Tags: jquery

My jquery is working locally but not when I publish to the site.  I looked at it in chrome and saw a couple of warnings related to the facebook link, nothing about the jquery.  I use godaddy for hosting and looked through the help there and didn't see anything i needed to do to get it to work.  web address is www.deischerphotography.com  any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: your `<div id="fader">` element is empty... that is why nothing is shown

Comment: The fader div has the comment..which is shown but no images.

Comment: <div id="fader">
         Welcome to my online portfolio.  Click on the picture or Gallery.  Enjoy - Brian
        <?php
            $dir='pics/wm/*';
            foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
            { 
              echo "<div>";
           echo "<img src='$file' width='650' height='475'/>";
              echo "</div>";
            }
       ?>  
    </div>

Comment: If you go to view source of your page you can see `<div id="fader">Welcome to my online portfolio. Click on the picture or Gallery. Enjoy - Brian
    <!-- <a class="button" href="#" id="next">Next</a>
   <a class="button" href="#" id="prev">Prev</a>
-->
</div>` so there are no `div` inside `#fader`

Answer (score 2):

For the error `FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()`

Add &status=0 to your js.src URL to make the warning disappear, ie:

```
//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&status=0
```

The default args for init() are used if not explicitly provided: status arg default is true - which makes the FB script call getLoginStatus() at startup, which complains because an app ID is needed for that function call.

FB social plugins doesn't need an app ID - they are rendered into an iframe originating from facebook.com, so FB login status and cookies as accessible to them.